# Converting Memory Map *.qct files into QGIS?

Tags: qgis

i have created a bunch of raster base maps in Memory Map software (ie georeferenced tiff's) that are Memory map specific format (*.qct).

Is there a way to import these or convert these into QGIS at all?

Comment: I'm afraid there is no open source driver for that closed source format.

Comment: OK thanks. So what would be the best way to bring my base maps in. Go back tot he original tiffs and georeference in QGIS?

Comment: Yes, use open source data formats from the start.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to export .QCT files. The easiest is to use Global Mapper (commercial software at http://www.globalmapper.com). Other options include a free (now discontinued) application called 'OZIMAPTRANS' (will need to google that to find a copy), and some python code that can be found at http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/608112, and if you are really adventurous some C++ code at http://www.sat.dundee.ac.uk/~arb/qct/. I am a heavy user of Global Mapper so would recommend that as my first choice, as it will keep the georeferencing and allow you to import into QGIS in mutiple formats (.tif, .jpg ect)

Comment: Thanks Mac. Really appreciate the advice! Do you know if a free trial, or legacy version of Global Mapper exists? At the price of the full version it's difficult to justify for a one off use  :( 


Unfortunately I'm not an 'expert in Python' either as is a prerequisite for ozimaptrans. 

Nice to know there are solutions but really looking for a cheap(ish) quick fix for about 20 files is all. 

Cheers

Comment: Global Mapper has a free trial and you should be able to open the QCT file, but believe it is limited in export options. OZIMAPTRANS doesn't need python (standalone application). If you can make the QCT files available via Dropbox/FTP etc I can attempt to convert them.

Comment: Thanks Mac. There is a free two week trial so I'll see how I go. I'm presuming best format is something like geotiff??

Comment: Thanks Mac. 2 week free trial works great but only let me convert two maps! I have two more. Let me know if you think you can help, best way to connect you (google drive is easiest for me)

Comment: Share it via Google Drive or Dropbox and send me a link to admin at gtechsquared dot com

Comment: OziMapTrans1309 can be downloaded here: http://chomikuj.pl/sebus1201/GEOPORTAL+-+pobieranie+map/OziMapTrans_v1.3.0.9,3277853770.zip%28archive%29. No installation, runs from a folder. Starts in German language. Find tab: Einstellungen » Sprache: English